# In which order are nodes inserted when they are created?

Tags: database, drupal

In Drupal, if you want to insert something into the node table, 'nid' can be null, but 'vid' can't. The inverse is true for the node_revision table.

In which order are nodes inserted when they are created?

I can't insert into the node table, because I don't have the revision ID; I can't insert into the node_revision table, because I don't have a node ID.

Also, is there some kind of function available that can easily do this insert for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code of the [`node_save` function is available](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/node_save/6) ; did you try to see how it's working ?

Here's the part that relates to node creation :

```
if ($node->is_new) {
  _node_save_revision($node, $user->uid);
  drupal_write_record('node', $node);
  db_query('UPDATE {node_revisions} SET nid = %d WHERE vid = %d', $node->nid, $node->vid);
  $op = 'insert';
}
```

Apparently, it first saves the revision of the node, and, only then, saves the node itself.

After that, the node_revisions record is updated, to put the value of the nid.

If you want t save a node, you shouldn't write code that would do that for you : you just have to call `node_save`, and it'll save the node, call the required hooks, and all that.

Comment: That was spot on. Thanks so much!

Comment: You're welcome :-) (That's one nice thing I love about PHP and open-source : if you want to know how it works, you can always look at the source code ;-) ) ;; Have fun !

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 7, the order is inverted, compared to Drupal 6: First the node is saved, and then the node revision is saved.

```
// Save the node and node revision.
if ($node->is_new) {
  // For new nodes, save new records for both the node itself and the node
  // revision.
  drupal_write_record('node', $node);
  _node_save_revision($node, $user->uid);
  $op = 'insert';
}
```

Also when a node is updated, the node is first saved, and then the node revision is saved.

```
  // For existing nodes, update the node record which matches the value of
  // $node->nid.
  drupal_write_record('node', $node, 'nid');
  // Then, if a new node revision was requested, save a new record for
  // that; otherwise, update the node revision record which matches the
  // value of $node->vid.
  if (!empty($node->revision)) {
    _node_save_revision($node, $user->uid);
  }
  else {
    _node_save_revision($node, $user->uid, 'vid');
    $update_node = FALSE;
  }
  $op = 'update';
```

Once the node revision is saved, the node row is updated.

```
if ($update_node) {
  db_update('node')
    ->fields(array('vid' => $node->vid))
    ->condition('nid', $node->nid)
    ->execute();
}
```

In Drupal 7, the vid field for the node table can be `NULL`, while both the nid, and the vid fields for the node_revision are not `NULL`, although the value of nid is 0 by default.